# Is it safe to use an async anonymous function in app.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With Mongoose.find() no longer accepting callbacks, I am thinking of implementing my app.get() in this way:

```js
app
    .route("/webclips")
    .get(async(req, res) => {
        await Webclip.find({}).then((result) => res.send(result));
    })
```

But I'm wondering, is it safe to make the (req,res) anonymous function asynchronous like this?

Comment: Many ppl use async handler, but i think you might have to deal with a own custom middleware that can handle promises by handle rejections and calling next... maybe https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router is something to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does, but `await/async`  does nothing there, because in the end you are using `then` where you performed `callback function`.

in other word of the `callback` is a function that is passed to another function.

i don't think its a good idea to mixed those paradigms.just choose one.

i like to use `await/async` because its more readable, and handling error with `try/catch` to make it compactly

accoirding to your error message, it means that you need to convert the code to use `async/await`. [Mongoose PR](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/curriculum/pull/25189)

it would be like:

```
app
    .route("/webclips")
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        const result = await Webclip.find({})
        res.send(result)
    })
```

for better approach, put them inside `try/catch`,

```
app
    .route("/webclips")
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        try{
           const result = await Webclip.find({})
           res.send(result) //return sc 200
        }catch(err){
           res.sendStatus(404) // no data found
           //with message
           //res.status(404).status({msg: 'no data found')
        }
       
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! But what did you mean when you said "it does"? Do you mean it's a good idea to do it this way instead of say app.get('/webclips', handleGetRequest) where handleGetRequest is an async function?

Comment: yes, its a good idea to do it in that way. but if your application will be much bigger in the feature, consider to use `pattern for separation of concern` like you said `app.get('/webclips', handleGetRequest)`.